# Unable to reset metamask account

Tags: blockchain, metamask

I have been working on a DApp recently and it requires me to clear history of an my accounts in metamask wallet. I have read several tutorials but could not clear the transaction history. I go to the 3 dots then settings then advanced then clear activity tab data then clear.
There's a loader for 1-2 seconds saying - "Connecting to Sepolia network" , then it disappears. When I go back and check, the activity section is still not blank.
I obtained these free test ethers by doing some mining.
How to clear this ? Please helpp.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the state of your Metamask account basically means to alter the history of the blockchain. You cannot change or mutate the blockchain's history at your will. That is the whole purpose of using a blockchain.

Comment: no, you can clear the activities in the activity tab (as shown in pic) of metamask account